# Powershell - Password encryption/decryption with key

Tags: powershell, encryption

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the password using the powershell. However not able to successfully decrypt

**My code**:

```
#Encryption
$KeyStoragePath="C:\Temp\Password"
$KeyFileName="AESKey.AES.Key"
$CreateKey = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($CreateKey)
$CreateKey | out-file ".\$KeyFileName"

$GetKey = Get-Content "$KeyStoragePath\$KeyFileName"
$CredentialsStoragePath = "C:\Temp\Password\"
$CredentialsFileName = "sec-string"
$PasswordSecureString = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$PasswordSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $GetKey | Out-File -FilePath "$CredentialsStoragePath\$CredentialsFileName"
```

This successfully creates a secure file with secure string in it. However, cannot decrypt it with the key.

```
#Decrypt

$MyPasswordFile = "C:\Temp\Password\sec-string"

$MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $CreateKey
```

**Error**

```
$MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $CreateKey
ConvertTo-SecureString : Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
At line:1 char:43
+ $MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $CreateKey
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the right things in the right places. You should be decrypting the *password* with the *key*

```
#Encryption
$KeyStoragePath="C:\Temp\Password"
$KeyFileName="AESKey.AES.Key"
$CreateKey = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($CreateKey)
$CreateKey | out-file "$KeyStoragePath\$KeyFileName"

$GetKey = Get-Content "$KeyStoragePath\$KeyFileName"
$CredentialsStoragePath = "C:\Temp\Password\"
$CredentialsFileName = "sec-string"
$PasswordSecureString = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$PasswordSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $GetKey | Out-File -FilePath "$CredentialsStoragePath\$CredentialsFileName"

#Decrypt

$MyPasswordFile = "C:\Temp\Password\sec-string"


$MyPassword = Get-Content $MyPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $GetKey


# Additional code below will change to plain text but this is bad practice. You should not need the plaintext password. You can create a credential from the secure string

$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($MyPassword)
$UnsecurePassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Comment: Thank you @Scepticalist.

I tried your code block, I dont see see the error which I initially posted. However, it returns only this _System.Security.SecureString_

Comment: That's what you requested in your code: `$MyPassword = Get-Content $MyPasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $GetKey`. You need to convert the secure string if you want plain text.

Comment: See additional code above. But this is bad practice. You should not need the plaintext password. You can create a credential from the secure string